# How to add custom gesture to a tab in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, gesture

I have a tabbarController:

```
UITabBarController* tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
UIViewController* view1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController* view2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:view1, view2, nil];
```

I want to add a long press gesture to view1's tab button(called tabBarItem)
or just add a long press gesture to the tabbar.

How could I do?

Thanks. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't add the long press gesture to the UITabBaritem and not possible solution for this unless you have your custom TabBar.

Comment: Well that's a weird requirement, you will have a tap already, whats the use of Long Press gesture, if you want create simple TabView of type UIView with custom view buttons and add Long Gesture, and add the TabView, on window to the bottom of the screen, by hiding the tabbar from Storyboard.

Comment: @iphonic thank you. Yes, we have a weird requirement:-) Users won't use this feature, we put it in a debug mode for developers test convenience.

Comment: @GhanshyamTomar Thank you. I finally add this gesture to the tabbar not the tabBarItem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put your UITabbarController Methods

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
```

and than use this for add gesture->

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longRecog = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressed)];

[tabBarController.tabBar addGestureRecognizer:longRecog];
```

and the selector is -

```
-(void)longPressed{
    //Long pressed Occures

}
```